# how to move file from current directory to another in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have the file and the directory in two variables.

```
 $file = /dir1/dir2/dir3/file1.txt

 $folder = /fol1/fol2/fol3
```

I am using the below :

```
 mv $file $folder
```

But I am not able to move the $file to the directory $folder.

The shell doesnt throw any error, it's just I just dont see the file in the destination folder.

Comment: Your script obviously won't work. But tell us what you mean by "I am not able to ...". Tell us specifically what errors you get.

Comment: I dont get any error. it's just I dont see the file in the destination folder.

Comment: I really doubt that. Read the answer below anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should not be spaces or `$` when assigning variables:

```sh
file=/dir1/dir2/dir3/file1.txt
folder=/fol1/fol2/fol3
```

and variables are recommended to be quoted when being expanded:

```sh
mv "$file" "$folder"
```

Comment: And what if I want to move directly the file(without variable ) to the directory in variable,  so mv file1.txt "$folder"  will this work ?

Comment: Yes it will. Also try to learn about relative and absolute paths.